# *ngIf async pipe angular merge with another observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Please give me some ideas of workaround for my app! I am trying to switch dynamicly template in my component but have odd behavior. Thanks! Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-era9lu)

**What I want basically:** I want to recieve async data (node) from service in my alert component, and show this data (node) in my #initTemplate, then I want to take id of this data (node), send request with this id and get another data (styles) which I want to display in my #stylesTemplate.
Both templates are in my alert component.

**What's my problem?**
I realized desired behavior of my component, but this is not exactly what I need... 
What I am doing:
1. Click on "pushData" button
2. Look at my alert component
3. Click on change template button **(!! component disappears !!)** 
4. Click on "pushData" again
5. Look at my component with changed template

**I need to switch component's template  without it's disappearing.**

Here is my simplified alert component (see also at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-era9lu) working sample)

```
class AlertComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private subscription: Subscription;
    message: any;

    node$: Observable<{}>;
    styles$: Observable<{}>;

    constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

    activeInit: boolean = true;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.node$ = this.dataService.getAsyncData().pipe(share());


        this.styles$ = this.node$.pipe(
            mergeMap(node => {
                if(!!node) {
                  // I need node here, because getSecondAsyncData send request with this data
                    return this.dataService.getSecondAsyncData(node);
                }
                else return of(null);
            }));
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {

    }

    openSecond() {
        this.activeInit = false;
    }

    openFirst() {
      this.activeInit = true;
    }

    close() {
        this.dataService.sendNodeToSubscribe(null);
    }
```

**And here is my html with both templates:**

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="activeInit ? initTemplate : stylesTemplate"></ng-container>

<ng-template #initTemplate>
    <div class="card left-settings position-fixed" *ngIf="(node$ | async) as node;">
        <div class="row justify-content-end mx-0">
            <div class="col-0">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-ghost-light p-1 px-2" (click)="close()">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row custom-width">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <button (click)="openSecond()">switch second template</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #stylesTemplate>
    <div class="card left-settings position-fixed" *ngIf="(styles$ | async) as styles;">
        <div class="row justify-content-end mx-0">
            <div class="col-0">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-ghost-light p-1 px-2" (click)="close()">
          Close
        </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row custom-width">
            <label>{{styles.isIcon}}</label>
            <label>{{styles.radius}}</label>
      <button (click)="openFirst()">switch first template</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

**Thank you !!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just have to replace below code,

use **BehaviorSubject** : A BehaviorSubject holds one value. When it is subscribed it emits the value immediately. A Subject doesn't hold a value.

```
private subject = new Subject<any>();
```

with

```
private subject = new BehaviorSubject(new String());
```

here's is updated [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkuj56?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts)

**Updated!!**

**Thank you!!** Nice advice, that's work fine, but I need my component to be hidden before recieved real data. To do that, I modified your solution, now I use this:

```
private subject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

Comment: Thank you! But now my alert component always activated because of BehaviorSubject, I suppose.
The main idea of this logic is that I have some list of items, and when I click on some of this item, alert component opens with item's information. It's important that before click my alert component need to be hidden

Comment: Thats really works, but for me better to use 
private subject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
instead of
private subject = new BehaviorSubject(new String());
because I need my component to be hidden before send real data
thank you one more time!